# NullPointerException using fragments with textview

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on `tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` but i have absolutely no idea why! I have declared the textView in the XML file and initialized it inside onCreateView. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant section for the java code:

```
public class TestConnection extends Fragment {
    public TestConnection() {

    }


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    //button pressed to get the items
    Button getAllItems;

    //declare list view
    TextView tv;

    //Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //Make an arrayList containing all items
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList;

    //url to get items
    private static String urlAllItems = "http://jamesalfei.netne.net/php/get_all_items.php";

    //JSON node/tag names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ITEMS = "items";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    //items array
    JSONArray items = null;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sql_layout,
                container, false);
        getAllItems = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.SQLGetItems);

        //listview
        tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sqltv); 

        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        getAllItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                retreiveProducts();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

and here is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SQLGetItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/getSQL" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sqltv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SQLGetItems"
            android:text="@string/sqlLabel" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Apologies if i have used any bad coding practices, but i'm VERY new to android programming!

Comment: Post your LogCat errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for your TextView in wrong view. You should be searching inflated view, not parent's view, mostly because you are not added there in your `onCreateView()`. So replace:

```
tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sqltv);
```

with this

```
tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sqltv);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it to "view." for both textView and Button and it works great now! Thank you!

However now i have errors with the SQL connection...BACK TO WORK!

Comment: Any idea how to resolve mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 3):

The View isn't attached to anything because you use `false` as the third parameter in `inflate()`. So you need to scope `findViewById()` to the layout that has your TextView. Use:

```
tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sqltv);
```